# getting numbers and words from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have divs with ids like

```
<div class="clickme" id="this_div_2"></div>
```

and when the user clicks I want to get both the this_div portion as one string and the id as a separate variable. So only the _ before the number would not be part of what I want to end up with

at the minute I'm using

```
$(".clickme").click(function(event) {
    var divId = event.target.id.match(/\d+/);
    alert(divId);
});
```

which alerts the number just fine, but how can I get the this_div as a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex match:

```
"this_div_2".match(/(\D+?)_(\d+)/);
//=> ["this_div_2", "this_div", "2"]
```